# How to change number of maximum threads in LAMPP

Tags: lamp, concurrent-users

How do I change maximum number of concurrent users in LAMPP. I found answers for apache and XAMPP but that does not solve my problem.

I have also tried changing this file, `opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-mpm.conf`, but I do not see any effect on changing any parameter. I am using apache jmeter for testing.

I have tried changing MaxClients too as said here. http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_apache_web_server_for_maximum_concurrent_connections_or_increase_max_clients_in_apache#mpm_prefork_module

Here is my httpd-mpm.conf,

```
#
# Server-Pool Management (MPM specific)
# 

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
# Note that this is the default PidFile for most MPMs.
#
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    PidFile "logs/httpd.pid"
</IfModule>

#
# Only one of the below sections will be relevant on your
# installed httpd.  Use "apachectl -l" to find out the
# active mpm.
#

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers          5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of worker threads
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers             2
    MaxClients         1000
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads         75 
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of worker threads
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads         75
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# NetWare MPM
# ThreadStackSize: Stack size allocated for each worker thread
# StartThreads: Number of worker threads launched at server startup
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads, to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads
# MaxThreads: Maximum number of worker threads alive at the same time
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: Maximum  number of connections a thread serves. It
#                         is recommended that the default value of 0 be set
#                         for this directive on NetWare.  This will allow the
#                         thread to continue to service requests indefinitely.
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# OS/2 MPM
# StartServers: Number of server processes to maintain
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads per process, 
#                  to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads per process
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: Maximum number of connections per server process
<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads          5
    MaxSpareThreads         10
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# The maximum number of free Kbytes that every allocator is allowed
# to hold without calling free(). In threaded MPMs, every thread has its own
# allocator. When not set, or when set to zero, the threshold will be set to
# unlimited.
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree            2048
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the max threads for whichever MPM module is actually in use.  You can figure it out by running either `apachectl -V` or `httpd -V` depending on how it is named in your Linux distribution.

```
apachectl -V | grep -i mpm
Server MPM: event
```

Then set the number of threads for the event mpm module.

```
httpd -V | grep -i mpm
Server MPM: Prefork
```

Then set the number of threads for the prefork mpm module.